# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in cart.js

Tags: javascript, list, arguments

I'm getting

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list | in cart.js file

```
// Purchase button.
        add('<button onclick="yaCounter44762137.reachGoal('zakaz'); return true;" class="btn btn-primary cart-purchase-button" type="button"></button>')
```

Comment: You can see the error in the syntax highlighter, escape quotes i.e. `.reachGoal(\'zakaz\')`

Comment: Code within code within code is just begging for quoting errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you escape the single quotes like this:

```
add('<button onclick="yaCounter44762137.reachGoal(\'zakaz\'); return true;" class="btn btn-primary cart-purchase-button" type="button"></button>');
```

It'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can change the zakaz in double quotes. It would make things a lot easier to do.

```
add('<button onclick="yaCounter44762137.reachGoal("zakaz"); return true;" class="btn btn-primary cart-purchase-button" type="button"></button>');
```

Or you can even use one double quote and put everything else in a single quote:

```
add("<button onclick=yaCounter44762137.reachGoal('zakaz'); return true;' class='btn btn-primary cart-purchase-button' type='button'></button>");
```